# Linux: Can't change file permissions being in the same group as the file

Tags: linux, permissions

So I have a file:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 joe web 35046982 Nov  4 16:54 app.log
```

I am in *web* group:

```
[sam@proj log]$ id
uid=5067(sam) gid=5071(sam) groups=505(web),5071(sam)
```

But I can't change the permissions:

```
[sam@proj log]$ chmod 777 app.log 
chmod: changing permissions of `app.log': Operation not permitted
```

**More background:**

This is for a deployment script. Many users can run it with their own user and they all need to be able to do stuff like adding write permissions to log file. I thought assigning the file to a group and then adding all users to that group would work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Only privileged users (root) can chown a file. At most, if you're the owner of the file you can change its group with chgrp.

#### From the chown man page

> Only the root user can change the owner of a file. You can change
>   the group of a file only if you are a root user or if you own the
>   file. If you own the file but are not a root user, you can change
>   the group only to a group of which you are a member.

Comment: The topic started had issue with `chmod` actually.

Answer (score 5):

I think that only privileged users can change permission of files that doesn't belong to them. In your case, you are not joe and you are not a privileged user, so you can't change file permissions.

Comment: What does "privileged user" mean?

Comment: It means a user which can do anything on the system, `root` for example.

Answer (score 1):

What filesystem is this on? Is this a network share? is this on NFS? Im guessing its on NFS, so chekc your export options and make sure you're exporting with full permissions to that group id...

Comment: It's ext3. What are "export options" and how do I export with full permissions to a group ID?

Comment: The export options Sidhu is referring to are NFS(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_file_system) export options. The only way I know of to export full permissions are to give it full permissions on the host.